# How to create a new CSV file and then store it in Google Cloud Storage?

Tags: python, csv, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

I have this code:

```
import csv
from google.cloud import storage
import os

os.environ["Credientials"]
storage_client = storage.Client()

mylist = ['Row1','Row2','Row3']  # Rows I'm making for CSV file

with open('Afile.csv', 'w') as myfile:
   wr = csv.writer(myfile, quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL)  # Making CSV file
   wr.writerow(mylist)

s = myfile

def upload_blob(bucket_name, source_file_name, destination_blob_name):
   """Uploads a file to the bucket."""
   storage_client = storage.Client()
   bucket = storage_client.get_bucket(bucket_name)
   blob = bucket.blob(destination_blob_name)
   blob.upload_from_filename(source_file_name)
   print('File {} uploaded to {}.'.format(
     source_file_name,
     destination_blob_name))

upload_blob('BucketName', s ,'storage location') # Uploading the newly made CSV file to Google Cloud Storage
```

Where a new CSV file is made ( referred to by `s`) and I am trying to upload that newly made file to Google Cloud storage, instead of uploading it from a local file path. When I run this, I get the following error:

```
TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object
```

How could I get this working so I can make a newly made CSV file and then upload it to Google Cloud Storage? If this is possible?

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2):

```py
with open('Afile.csv', 'w') as myfile:
    wr = csv.writer(myfile, quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL)  # Making CSV file
    wr.writerow(mylist)

    s = myfile
```

Here `s` is a `file like object` rather than a string or bytes object.  You are passing the file itself essentially instead of the name of the file.  You probably should pass `Afile.csv` instead as a string.

Comment: This does not answer the question as it is asking about uploading the newly created csv file.